# Box2d wind resistance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I'd like to make game with some windmill in it and want to make wind via b2vec2 gravity vector. I can't find some clear explanation about wind resistance. Is it possible with box2d? May I ask you to point me to necessary functions and documentation please.

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide more information on what exactly you're trying to accomplish?  Are you trying to model fan physics (blades pushing a gas) in 2D, or something simpler, like a force being applied to objects within some portion of the level (like what you'd see in a classic 2D game)?  Something other than this?  Also, what does wind *resistance* (drag force) have to do with what you're simulating?

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is most likely impossible with box2d, as that would involve the physics being simulated in 3d, while box2d only does 2d physics. If I was you, I would just fake the animation. By having the blades of the windmill in a separate CCSprite than the body of the windmill and then rotating the blades around the z-axis using a CCAnimation that matches the wind speed.

Comment: This answer won't be helpful to the OP.  First, all 2D games that do "physics" are obviously faking things, as the real world isn't 2D.  But most 3D phenomenon can be approximated in 2D simply by throwing out a dimension.  Second, this answer doesn't point to any resources that would be helpful (as the OP asked for).

Comment: So how exactly would you physically simulate a windmill in a 2d physics engine? Box2d only supports rotation along the z-axis. How ever it has no notion of a force applied in the z direction. Thus making something like a windmill impossible to simulate. P.S. It is incredibly easy to fake a windmills animation... Just by rotating the blades at a fixed speed.

Comment: I agree that the question is unclear.  But this is more a comment than an answer.  With this in mind, how specifically would you suggest they go about faking it?

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham By having the blades of the windmill in a separate CCSprite than the body of the windmill and then rotating the blades around the z-axis using a CCAnimation that matches the wind speed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, it is really helpful. I will try solve my problem a little bit different.

Comment: @RTS: I understand the assumption this answer makes now.  Apologies for the down-vote, though I waited too long and it won't let me remove it unless the answer gets edited.

Answer (score 1):

**For games**

Depending on the game, you may not need to worry about drag force (wind resistance).  You could probably get away with pushing objects in the direction the wind is blowing, using an `ApplyForce` or messing with gravity (like you mentioned in the question).

**If you really want to model wind resistance**

Looks like `linearDampening` could be helpful, though unrealistic.  True air resistance isn't linear.

You could also do an `ApplyForce` every frame, opposite the velocity.  Unfortunately its been a while since I've taken my mechanics class, so I can't help you with the code, but you could [look at this wikipedia article for the formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_%28physics%29)

I stole most of this info from this thread:

http://www.box2d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2718

**If you are still having problems**

I made some assumptions in my answer.  I assumed that you're making rudimentary approximations of things like wind and air resistance.  I also assumed you're not truly trying to model a gas pushing a fan, as you probably won't have much luck doing that in 2D, and even if you tried, I can't imagine it adding much to your game.

If you're still confused, try adding some example code to your question, or describe what you are trying to simulate in more detail.

Comment: How would that help the OP make a windmill at all? Did you even read the question?

Comment: @RTS: I made assumptions based on: wind + game.  I will add a comment asking for clarification.